# proximity alert and battery drain

Tags: android, performance, gps, proximity, battery

I'm working on a project where I track the position of the phone every 5 minutes using the requestSingleUpdate method.
Doing this the phone's battery last all day long.

I want to check if the phone is going close to special locations that I've geocoded. 
I had in mind to use proximity alert, but I don't know exactly how it works.
Will it only use the location provided by my previous requestSingleUpdate or will it set its own requestLocationUpdates ?

And what about the battery consumption ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Android [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) it will use it's own method of checking location and will do it every 4 mins when the screen is off.

So you don't need to use your own locationListener, If you did want to get the users location for other means. Use the [PASSIVE_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER) (as of API8) that way when ever the proximityAlert does a location request or ANY other app that uses the LocationManager triggers a request, the PASSIVE_PROVIDER will also be triggered.

Comment: thank's, in that case I've to implement my own proximity alert logic :-(